# Collection of derived classes with extended interfaces. How to access derived interface without dynamic cast?

Tags: c++, oop

Say that I've got an abstract object of type "Animal". Animal has the public pure virtual method "eat".

I want to derive Animal into a "Dog" and "Cat", each with an extended interface. For example, I want Dog to have a public method "chaseTail" and Cat to have a public method "destroyFurniture".

I want to make a collection of animals in a "World" object.

I need to be able to retrieve these animals from World with a "getAnimalAtPosition" method, and be able to arbitrarily call chaseTail or destroyFurniture on the Animal I got.

I'd like to avoid the slow dynamic_cast, testing if the position is a given animal or hoisting chaseTail and destroyFurniture into Animal, but I seem to be backed into a corner here.

Is there another way?

Comment: By my experience of three pets, animal methods should go other way around; dog destroys furniture while cat chases it's tail pretty often. ;)

Comment: Is the "slow" dynamic_cast really slow enough to make a difference here? Most of the time people try to optimize away dynamic_cast, virtual functions, etc., it's misguided. And likewise, why would you like to avoid the other two possibilities?

Comment: More importantly: "I need to… be able to to arbitrarily call chaseTail or destroyFurniture on the Animal I got". What do you want to happen if you call chaseTail on a cat? Nothing? An exception? Magically converting the cat into a dog? (Of course in real life, if you ask a cat to chase his tail, he will just give you a scathing look, especially if you've done so under the mistaken illusion that he's a dog.)

Comment: I mean aribitrarily in the sense that the client using the code can call these whenever they want, on whatever condition they want. Having to hoist "chaseTail" and "destroyFurniture" into Animal and then also having to deal with the error of calling chaseTail on a Cat is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: type traits it's inappropriate here?

Answer (score 5):

The [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is a viable solution.  The solution has two main participants:

- Elements: The distinct types with a common parent that will accept a Visitor.  In this case, the Elements are `Cat` and `Dog` with the common parent being `Animal`.
- Visitor: The class that will visit Elements, and can invoke Element specific operations as it has a handle to the specific Element type.

For this example, begin with the elements (Animal, Cat, and Dog):

```
class Animal
{
public:
  virtual ~Animal() {}
  virtual void eat() = 0;
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
public:
  void destroyFurniture();
  void eat(); 
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
public:
  void chaseTail();
  void eat();
};
```

Next, create a Visitor that will 'visit' each Element.  The Visitor will know the type it is operating on, so it can use methods on both the specific Elements, such as `Cat::destroyFurniture()` and `Dog::chaseTail()`:

```
class Visitor
{
public:
   void visitDog( Dog& dog ) { dog.chaseTail();        }
   void visitCat( Cat& cat ) { cat.destroyFurniture(); }
};
```

Now, add a pure virtual method to `Animal` that accepts a `Visitor` as an argument: `void Animal::accept( Vistor& )`.  The idea is to pass a `Visitor` to an `Animal`, and allow the virtual method to resolve to the specific runtime type.  Once the virtual call is resolved, the implementation can invoke the specific `visit` method on the `Visitor`.

```
class Animal
{
public:
  ...
  virtual void accept( Visitor& ) = 0;
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
public:
  ...
  virtual void accept( Visitor& visitor ) { visitor.visitCat( *this ); }
};
```

Notice how the virtual method is used to resolve to the specific Element type, and that that each element's `accept` implementation will invoke a method on the Visitor.  This allows for execution to branch based on type without the use of `dynamic_cast`, and is commonly referred to as [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

---

[Here](http://ideone.com/h8g7f) is a compilable example that demonstrates the pattern in use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Cat;
class Dog;

class Visitor
{
public:
   void visitCat( Cat& cat );
   void visitDog( Dog& dog );
};

class Animal
{
public:
  virtual ~Animal() {}
  virtual void eat() = 0;
  virtual void accept( Visitor& ) = 0;
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
public:
  void destroyFurniture()         { cout << "Cat::destroyFurniture()" << endl; }
  void eat()                      { cout << "Cat::eat()" << endl;              }  
  void accept( Visitor& visitor ) { visitor.visitCat( *this );                 }
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
public:
  void chaseTail()                { cout << "Dog::chaseTail()" << endl; }
  void eat()                      { cout << "Dog::eat()" << endl;       }  
  void accept( Visitor& visitor ) { visitor.visitDog( *this );          }
};

// Define Visitor::visit methods.
void Visitor::visitCat( Cat& cat ) { cat.destroyFurniture(); }
void Visitor::visitDog( Dog& dog ) { dog.chaseTail();        }

int main()
{
  typedef std::vector< Animal* > Animals;
  Animals animals;
  animals.push_back( new Cat() );
  animals.push_back( new Dog() );

  Visitor visitor;  
  for ( Animals::iterator iterator = animals.begin();
        iterator != animals.end(); ++iterator )
  {
    Animal* animal = *iterator;
    // Perform operation on base class.
    animal->eat();
    // Perform specific operation based on concrete class.
    animal->accept( visitor );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Cat::eat()
Cat::destroyFurniture()
Dog::eat()
Dog::chaseTail()
```

---

Please note that in this example, `Visitor` is a concrete class.  However, it is possible for an entire hierarchy to be created for `Visitor`, allowing you to perform different operations based on the `Visitor`.

```
class Visitor
{
public:
   virtual void visitCat( Cat& ) = 0;
   virtual void visitDog( Dog& ) = 0; 
};

class FurnitureDestroyingVisitor: public Visitor
{
   virtual void visitCat( Cat& cat ) { cat.destroyFurniture(); }
   virtual void visitDog( Dog& dog ) {} // Dogs cannot destroy furniture.
};
```

One major drawback to the Visitor pattern is that adding `Elements` may require making changes to the `Visitor` classes.  The general rule of thumb is:

- If the Element hierarchy is likely to change, it may be easier to define operations on the base Element class.  In this example, if `Cow`, `Horse`, and `Pig` need to be added, then it may be easier to add a virtual `doTypical` method to `Animal`.
- If the Element hierarchy is stable, but the algorithms operating on the Elements are changing, then the Visitor pattern may be a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a visitor pattern thing with full knowledge of all classes.

Comment: Further explanation of "visitor pattern" would be grealy appreciated.

Comment: I think this is more of what I'm looking for but I don't quite know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

A desire to discover the dynamic type of a polymorphic hierarchy at runtime usually indicates a design error. You could instead try something like this:

```
struct Animal
{
    virtual ~Animal()             {              }
    void eat()                    { doEat();     }
    void performTypicalActivity() { doTypical(); }
private:
    virtual void doEat() = 0;
    virtual void doTypical() = 0;
};

struct Cat : Animal
{
    void destroyFurniture();
    void purr();
private:
    virtual void doTypical() { destroyFurniture(); purr(); }
};
```

Now you iterate over your collection and call `p->performTypicalActivity()` on every element.

Comment: What if the functions chaseTail and destroyFurniture required parameters?, like void Dog::chaseTail(int howLong) and void Cat::destroyFurniture(Furniture toBeDestroyed) and there were no good default values for these parameters?

Comment: @StevenLavoie: There isn't really enough context in your question to answer that. Whatever collection you have, the extra information you speak of has to come from somewhere, and it's possible that your problem has a solution that can be designed so that the information is already provided to the concrete instances by the time you need to iterate over them.