# Type Checking: see if a variable is inherited or is a certain class

Tags: c++, performance, templates, casting, static-members

I read that `dynamic_cast<THECLASS>(THEVARIABLE)` would return 0 if you tried to cast THEVARIABLE to THECLASS (assuming that THEVARIABLE is not a class of THECLASS and not a decedent of THECLASS). I heard that dynamic_cast is slower because it needs to do runtime checks. If I did many loops for object checking, wouldn't dynamic_cast be slow (like 100 objects)?

I was wondering if I made a static class to do type checking such as the following, would it be better (faster?) (ignore syntax errors if any):

```
class TYPECHECK {
public:
inline static bool isInt(int a) {
   return true;
}
template<typename wrongtype>
inline static bool isInt(wrongtype a) {
   return false;
}

[...]

private:
TYPECHECK();

};

int main() {
   int a = 5;
   char b = 'd';
   TYPECHECK::isInt(a);   //true
   TYPECHECK::isInt(b);   //false
   return 0; 
}
```

Assuming I did this for more complex types besides just int. Would this class implementation be faster than dynamic_cast (used for checking) if it were in a for loop?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

twsansbury has a good answer for recommending and including an example of the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to profile, **but probably not**. Although `dynamic_cast` has some overhead, it's optimized and should, in a proper implementation, be much faster than any user-implemented type identification method.

IMO however, if you need lots of casts, your design could be improved. Better ask about that ;)

Also, not that `dynamic_cast` only returns NULL if you cast to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks! I am doing something similar to Qt's QObject findChildren (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren) where I need to return an vector/list of objects that have inherited from a class. I viewed Qt's implementation and they compare classname strings of the object's superclass in qMetaObject. However I wanted to use either dynamic_cast or the static class (which ever is faster).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you need that for but you can take a look at boost's polymorphic casts - `polymorphic_cast` and `polymorpihc_downcast` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm)

They basically perform the same thing as `dynamic_cast` in DEBUG and a `static_cast` in RELEASE, so you have the safety when running in DEBUG and you have the speed when in RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, need of `dynamic_cast` means problems of architecture.
Think about virtual methods.

Comment: I am doing something similar to Qt's QObject findChildren (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren) where I need to return an vector/list of objects that have inherited from a class. Is there a better way to do it without dynamic_cast?

Comment: Well, you return list of QObject. Then you have two options -- you call their virtual methods or you KNOW their actual types, and do `static_cast`. First is preferred, but sometimes lead to incredible huge object class. Probably, you can reimplement findChildren in some major derivates with more concrete types, like QWidget do?

Dynamic cast is bad, Static cast in unwanted, but sometimes needed.

Comment: Btw I am not using Qt but somewhat mimicking its Gui functionality. Anyways, say you have a list of children from a parent, the parent can hold any child inherited from ObjectBase. If I asked for all ButtonClass children but the children vector has a mix of buttons and textfields, how would I do it without checking?

Comment: Keep two lists. You are asked not for objects, but for their behavior. You return not list of buttons and list of textfields, but list of pushable and list of editable.

Comment: I think it is a little more difficult than that. I mean if I kept two lists, one is pushable and the other is editable but I asked for ObjectBase instead of just pushable or editable. Since there is no "ObjectBase" list then I return an NULL pointer. If I did type checking, you would see that both lists came from ObjectBase. Same would go if I asked for VisualObject (VisualObject inherits ObjectBase and pushable and editable inherits off VisualObject).

Comment: @user654628: Although it would expand the `ObjectBase` interface slightly, you may benefit from using a [visitor pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125475/).  [Here](http://ideone.com/MZS65) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `dynamic_cast` walks through inheritance hierarchies as well so if you are doing it on your own as you said, you will have to make sure that any new class you add in the future is added to your checks here. This seems easy but very error-prone since one can easily forget such things and any new developer working on this will have to learn all this.

That said, performance-wise, you will have to profile but I doubt there will be a lot of difference because most of the indirections involved inside dynamic cast would be optimized away.