# How to access members in derived without downcast

Tags: c++

Say that I need to decode some messages into `Animal` objects which has a public member `type`. For each `Animal.type` I create a derived class: `Dog if type=0`, `Bird if type=1`, etc. and each type of Animal has a unique member `property`. Below is an abstract example:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(int type) : type(type) {}
    virtual ~Animal(){}
    int type;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    Dog(DogProperty property) : Animal(0)
    {
        this->property = property;
    }

    DogProperty property;
};

class Bird : public Animal
{
public:
    Bird(BirdProperty property) : Animal(1)
    {
        this->property = property;
    }

    BirdProperty property;
};
```

I have a method that takes in a message and returns an `Animal` object. Within the method, I use a third party library to decode the message. The same third party library also provides `DogProperty` and `BirdProperty`:

```
struct DogProperty {}; //provided by 3rd party libarary   
struct BirdProperty {}; //provided by 3rd party libarary
void decodeDog(char *msg, DogProperty *p); //provided by 3rd party libarary
void decodeBird(char *msg, BirdProperty *p); //provided by 3rd party libarary

Animal parseAnimalMessage(char *encodedMessage);
```

Now after `parseAnimalMessage`, I can identify the type of animal from `myAnimal.type` but I cannot access `property` as it is unique to the derived class. I know I can let `parseAnimalMessage` return `Animal*` and downcast `myAnimal` to the appropriate derived class but is there a way to avoid this?

I want to avoid derived class because I am using embedded system which has **RTTI disabled**.

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125475/collection-of-derived-classes-with-extended-interfaces-how-to-access-derived-in) which is very similar to mine, but I cannot find a way to implement the suggested "visitor" pattern here because I would need the visitor to return `DogProperty` or `BirdProperty`.

---

*Note: This does not work on my embedded system. `dynamic_cast` is not available*
Below is a working example using downcast.

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct DogProperty //provided by 3rd party libarary
{
    char pawShape;
    char tailShape;
};

struct BirdProperty //provided by 3rd party libarary
{
    char wingLength;
    char wingWidth;
};

void decodeDog(char *msg, DogProperty *p) //provided by 3rd party libarary
{
    p->pawShape = msg[2];
    p->tailShape = msg[3];
}

void decodeBird(char *msg, BirdProperty *p) //provided by 3rd party libarary
{
    p->wingLength = msg[2];
    p->wingWidth = msg[3];
}

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(int type) : type(type) {}
    virtual ~Animal(){}
    int type;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    Dog(DogProperty property) : Animal(0)
    {
        this->property = property;
    }

    DogProperty property;
};

class Bird : public Animal
{
public:
    Bird(BirdProperty property) : Animal(1)
    {
        this->property = property;
    }

    BirdProperty property;
};

Animal* readMessage(char *message)
{
    if (message[0] == '0')
    {
        DogProperty property;
        decodeDog(message, &property);
        return new Dog(property);
    }
    if (message[0] == '1')
    {
        BirdProperty property;
        decodeBird(message, &property);
        return new Bird(property);
    }
    // other animals
    return new Animal(-1);
}

void processDog(Dog *dog)
{
    cout<<"Dog Paw: ";
    cout<<dog->property.pawShape<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    char messageA[20] = "0-1030202da-0302s";
    char messageB[20] = "1-1032649sf-0239s";
    char messageC[20] = "2-1032298kd-0357s";

    Animal* myAnimal = readMessage(messageA);
    if (myAnimal->type == 0)
    {
        Dog *dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(myAnimal);
        processDog(dog);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The approach used here sort of flies in the face of most object-oriented design patterns. C++ has RTTI if you need it, but the idea is that generally you shouldn't care. Make a `Property` base, inherit as many times as necessary, give each of these a `decode` function.

Comment: Tip: Use constructor lists for properties as well. That avoids some of the `this->` mess in this code.

Comment: "Tell-Don't-Ask is a principle that helps people remember that object-orientation is about bundling data with the functions that operate on that data. It reminds us that rather than asking an object for data and acting on that data, we should instead tell an object what to do. This encourages to move behavior into an object to go with the data."  See https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html ....   In general, you do not 'down-cast' in an inheritance, instead simply invoke the virtual method against the pointer to the base class.

Comment: @2785528 yes, I think I should move `process()` to `Animal` and implement it in derived.

Comment: @tadman, I can't make a `property` base because `property` is handled by a 3rd party industrial standard library.

Comment: You can always wrap it in your own class structures.

Comment: @tadman, would you mind giving an example?

Comment: You literally just wrap their type in your type as a property.

Comment: @2785528 having a second thought, I cannot actually include `process()` in `Animal`. `property` is needed in many ways. It would make a mess if I try including everything in `Animal`. I'd like to make it a simple data struct.

Comment: @tadman, sorry I don't get it. Are you suggesting something like: `struct BaseProperty { ? myProperty; }` + `stuct MyDogProperty:public BaseProperty {DogProperty myProperty;}`, then `class Animal { BaseProperty property;}` and `class Dog {MyDogProperty property;}` ?

Comment: There's a bunch of ways of wrapping it, including `union`, which can get messy, or a proper class structure. The best one to choose depends on how you're receiving data. Right now it looks like you have to call the classes specifically, you're lacking factory methods, which is something you normally see used to delegate to the appropriate subclass.

Comment: Remember in C++ you can have overrides, so a `static` function on `Animal` could be like `Animal* with_property(DogProperty* p)` as well as `Animal* with_property(BirdProperty* p)` each of which specialize to handle that data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would use a virtual function in the base class that would be overridden in the derived classes.  For a general visitor pattern you would have something like this in `Animal`:

```
virtual void visit(AnimalVisitor &) = 0;
```

and you would implement that with something like

```
class AnimalVisitor {
 public:
    std::function<void (Dog *)>  dogVisitor;
    std::function<void (Bird *)> birdVisitor;

    AnimalVisitor(std::function<void (Dog *)>dv) : dogVisitor(dv) {}
    AnimalVisitor(std::function<void (Bird *)>bv) : birdVisitor(bv) {}
    AnimalVisitor(std::function<void (Dog *)>dv, std::function<void (Bird *)>bv) : dogVisitor(dv), birdVisitor(bv) {}
};
```

The implementation in Dog would be:

```
void visit(AnimalVisitor &v) override {
    if (v.dogVisitor) v.dogVisitor(this); }
```

and in main you would have

```
Animal* myAnimal = readMessage(messageA);
myAnimal->visit(processDog);
```

Comment: thanks. This does not work with my embedded system. it does not have `std::function`. RTTI is disabled, for the same reason `dynamic_cast` is also unavailable. Following @2785528 's suggestion, I should create `virtual void process();` in `Animal` and implement it in derived - unless I have better options.

Comment: @Anthony If you are using some specialized subset of C++ you need to mention exactly which one. In general it doesn't make sense to do these kind of things in embedded systems. Or to use C++... but that's another story.

Comment: If you don't have std::function, you may be able to use raw function pointers instead

Comment: @Lundin my project is in Arduino environment. Pretty new to this kind of things and also lacking knowledge in c/c++, almost thought they are interchangeable...

Comment: @ChrisDodd thanks, I tried raw function pointer but couldn't get it working - I have very limited knowledge in this, will continue to investigate off-work... I opted in an ugly solution by including all unique properties in the base class then access what is needed... just need a quick method to get the system running to advance my project